# Why need specify following styles when using VML?

Tags: css, vml

I am learning VML right now. And I noticed that each example contains two style definition as following:

```
        v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}

        o\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}
```

I know the `{behavior:url(#default#VML)` means apply the behaviour on the elements selected by `v\:*`. But I do not known what kind of elements do the `v\:*` select. And what is the behaviour `#default#VML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because VML is an XML based aproach, it needs a seperate namespace for all its elements.
To use a prefix in XML, a namespace needs to be declared. This one may look familiar:

```
<xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v" />
```

The namespace used for VML is commonly prefixed using the letter "v" but it could be anything.
The CSS selector `v\:*` simply selects any element <sub>(`*` stand for "any")</sub> prefixed with the letter "v". The backslash is just there to escape the colon.

VML is so called "Default Behaviour", predefined by the browser. The `#default` tells the browser to access build-in functionality,
`#VML` specifies which behavior.

Over at the The MSDN Library you can find more details on [Using DHTML Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [behavior Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).